# How to detect double-byte characters in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there anyway to identify if doublebyte characters exists within a string using preg_match or strpos?

I am receiving XML files with chinese language text mixed with English and would like to skip any files that contain the chinese text. The XML is utf-8 encoded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if (mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8') != strlen($string)) {
  // string contains multibyte characters
}
```